# How to Customize NetSuite's Vendor Center

Tags: netsuite

How can I customize the NetSuite Vendor Center? Is it even possible to customize other than using a Suitelet and putting a link in the top menu bar? I realize the question is pretty broad, so I've included some examples of what I'm looking to do, but I'm really wondering if NetSuite even allows these sorts of customizations in the Vendor Center.

Specifically, I'm looking for:

1. How can I change the way the Purchase Order form looks. It defaults to the expanded view.
2. How do I edit the Items sublist on the PO form to show other custom Transaction Line Fields.
3. How do I restrict the PO List view, so that Vendors can't choose from all the public saved searches marked as List views.

Answer (score 1):

My tendency for all of this sort of thing is to use a Netsuite website with a custom SSP application. The app will will have something like a vendors.ssp page that uses Netsuite's page permissions to limit it to vendors.

That page is just a simple page that I link to a React SPA using HashRouter from react-router-dom and navigation links put in a React.Portal.

REST endpoints are services/*.ss where that again use permissions to limit the callers to logged in vendors and I create a role that is not assigned to any user who can log in that actually accesses the Netsuite back end with all the permissions I need.

Easy to set up; way less ceremony than using Netsuite's Backbone based offering.

For front end validation my app has a folder that I can run with Parcel; AJAX calls are via a store where the real app accesses Netsuite but for testing it just pulls from cached XHR responses copied from dev tools.

For publishing I often just build a zip file and upload that using the advanced upload.
However recently I created a bundle that works with grunt watch that will let you upload anything seamlessly.

https://github.com/BKnights/grunt-netsuite

This feels super productive compared to Netsuite's Backbone based system.